# Why is there a 1 pixel gap on this div containing an image?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `overflow:hidden` that contains an image. On this image, there's a 1 pixel gap that's non existent on the original image, and it is still there on any other image I try. I've tried setting `padding: none`, and checking if that's cancelled by any inheritance, but there's nothing. I think it has to do with the border, but I'm not sure.
[image]

Sorry for the low res, but I had to zoom in.
Here the code is:

```css
.product-container{
  width: 225px;
  height: min-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px #dddddd solid;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.product-image{
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container" >
       <img class="product-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/931177/pexels-photo-931177.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
    </div>
```

If you zoom in, you can see the 1px gap, at least on my display.
I have a DPI of 100.

Comment: "f you zoom in, you can see the 1px gap" - what DPI are you using?

Comment: What is the purpose of `product-container`? You could apply all of those styles directly to the `img`.

Comment: I have other styling I'm applying, but figured it was irrelevant to the question, and didn't add anything.

Comment: I think you're just seeing an artifact of the generally crappy browser zoom. You've got a rasterised image and a vector border so there's going to be differences in how that zoom is applied. FYI, I only see the gap at 250%

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. I don't think there's anything I can do about that.

Comment: I think the problem is with your browser. I see no gap even when I zoom to 500%. Try to check it on a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

try make =>

width:100%;
height:100%;
for img

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could try taking the border-radius off the img container and place the border-radius in the product-image class